# Issue with replacing string by match in R

Tags: r, string, match

I want to replace the cell elements to "NA" if a cell element starts with "F" and  all trailing cell elements in a row.

How can I achieve this in R?

Any help is appreciated.

```
 Table: 

    043  N  005 E 013  F001 00000003789 0005254  0009009  NA   NA       NA        NA NA NA 
    045  N  006 E 005  F001 00000012456 0005447  0001007  NA   NA       NA        NA NA NA
    045  N  007 E 015  F001 00000014556 0005847  0001107  F001 00001587 00007814  NA NA NA
    045  N  007 E 015  L002 044 N  006  E 036    F001     00001587      00007814  NA NA NA


Output:

        043  N  005 E 013  NA   NA   NA  NA  NA   NA       NA        NA NA NA 
        045  N  006 E 005  NA   NA   NA  NA  NA   NA       NA        NA NA NA
        045  N  007 E 015  NA   NA   NA  NA  NA   NA       NA        NA NA NA
        045  N  007 E 015  L002 044  N   006 E    036      NA        NA NA NA
```

Please see the `dput` output

```
dput(head(Table))

structure(list(V29 = c("043", "045", "045", "043", "043", "044"
), V30 = c("N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N"), V31 = c("005", "006", 
"007", "004", "004", "005"), V32 = c("E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E"), V33 = c("013", "005", "035", "001", "001", "005"), V34 = c("F001", 
"F001", "F001", "L002", "L002", "F001"), V35 = c("000000037098944", 
"000000037098945", "000000037098919", "044", "044", "000000006844013"
), V36 = c("0005254", "0005447", "0005233", "N", "N", "0008090"
), V37 = c("0009009", "0010007", "0000904", "004", "004", "0001479"
), V38 = c("0005", "0001", "0005", "E", "E", "0021"), V39 = c(NA, 
NA, "F002", "036", "036", NA), V40 = c(NA, NA, "000000037098920", 
"F001", "F001", NA), V41 = c(NA, NA, "0005233", "000000004124126", 
"000000005660728", NA), V42 = c(NA, NA, "0000904", "0007249", 
"0007249", NA), V43 = c(NA, NA, "0006", "0011127", "0011127", 
NA), V44 = c(NA, NA, "F003", "0005", "0004", NA), V45 = c(NA, 
NA, "000000037098941", NA, "F002", NA), V46 = c(NA, NA, "0005233", 
NA, "000000006763171", NA), V47 = c(NA, NA, "0000904", NA, "0007249", 
NA), V48 = c(NA, NA, "0007", NA, "0011127", NA), V49 = c(NA, 
NA, "F004", NA, "0002", NA), V50 = c(NA, NA, "000000037098942", 
NA, "F003", NA), V51 = c(NA, NA, "0005233", NA, "000000037865325", 
NA), V52 = c(NA, NA, "0000904", NA, "0007249", NA), V53 = c(NA, 
NA, "0008", NA, "0011127", NA), V54 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "0003", 
NA), V55 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), V56 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    V57 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), V58 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), V59 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), V60 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), V61 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), V62 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), V63 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), V64 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), V65 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), V66 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), V67 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), V68 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), V69 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), V70 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), V71 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), V72 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), V73 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), V74 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), V75 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), V76 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), V77 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), V78 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    )), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x2294f40>)
```

Comment: Is that a `data.frame` or a `matrix`? It would help if your data were reproducible and easily copy/pasted. Can you paste the output from `dput(head(x))` into your question?

Comment: Its a data frame. Please see my question above for dput output. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started by truncating your data for brevity:

```
x <- x[,5:12]
```

Up front: I often soap-box about *not* using `apply` on a `data.frame`, since it implicitly converts the whole thing to a `matrix` with the highest-common class (typically `character`). However, in this case, it's actually what we want (strings, so we can `grepl` them). If there are actually numbers in your frame, they'll be up-converted, true, but unless your data is "large"-ish, it won't crush performance. (If it is, there are work-arounds.)

Ok, so let's first find where the strings are starting with `F`:

```
 t(apply(x, 1, function(a) grepl("^F", a)))
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]
# [1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [6,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

We want to convert everything with `TRUE`, sure, but also everything to the right of them. We can go row-wise using `cumany` (cumulative `any`):

```
t(apply(x, 1, function(a) cumany(grepl("^F", a))))
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7] [,8]
# [1,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
# [3,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
# [6,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
```

Now a simple replacement works:

```
x[ t(apply(x, 1, function(a) cumany(grepl("^F", a)))) ] <- NA
x
#    V33  V34  V35  V36  V37  V38  V39  V40
# 1: 013 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 2: 005 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 3: 035 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 4: 001 L002  044    N  004    E  036 <NA>
# 5: 001 L002  044    N  004    E  036 <NA>
# 6: 005 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Works great. This is exactly I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    if (sum(grepl('F',as.character(df[i,])))>0) {
        df[i,6:ncol(df)] <- NA
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address where there's a leading F in other columns (it's not just the one).

Comment: My mistake. I misread the question w.r.t. where the 'F' was to be found. Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited my answer to a version that works.

Comment: Still not right. If you compare the output of yours with the desired output (and my answer), you'll see that when you find an `F`, you always replace columns 6 and beyond, regardless of where it is found. The code needs to react to *where* in the row the `F` is found. (Also: you can simplify `sum(grepl(...))>0` to `any(grepl(...))`, slightly faster asymptotically.)